# PHP Bitwasp, signing a bitcoin-cash transaction

Tags: php, bitcoin, signing

I try to sign test bitcoin-cash transaction, and then broadcast.
For bitwasp version 0.0.35.0, the code is:

```
   $utxoOwnerPrivateKey = 'MyPrIvAtEKey';//public key is "16Dbmp13CqdLVwjXrd6amF48t7L8gYSGBj", note - the real private key is another
   $utxo = '5e44cdab9cb4a4f1871f2137ab568bf9ef2760e52816971fbaf0198f19e28378';
   $utxoAmount = 598558;
   $reciverPublicKey = '1EjCxux1FcohsBNGzY9KdF59Dz7MYHQyPN';
   $fee = 1000;

   $addressCreator = new \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Address\AddressCreator();

   $networkObject = \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Network\NetworkFactory::bitcoinCash();
   $keyPairInput = \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory::fromWif($utxoOwnerPrivateKey, null, $networkObject);


   $outpoint = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\OutPoint(\BitWasp\Buffertools\Buffer::hex($utxo, 32), 0);


   $transaction = \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\TransactionFactory::build()
       ->spendOutPoint($outpoint)
       ->payToAddress($utxoAmount - $fee, $addressCreator->fromString($reciverPublicKey, $networkObject) )
       ->get();

   echo "Unsigned transaction: " . $transaction->getHex() . '<BR><BR>';

   $signScript = \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Script\ScriptFactory::scriptPubKey()->payToPubKeyHash($keyPairInput->getPublicKey()->getPubKeyHash());
   $txOut = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\TransactionOutput($utxoAmount  - $fee, $signScript);

   $signer = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\Factory\Signer($transaction);

   $signatureChecker = \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Transaction\Factory\Checker\CheckerCreator::fromEcAdapter( \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin::getEcAdapter() ); // for version 0.0.35
   $signer->setCheckerCreator( $signatureChecker ); // for version 0.0.35
   $input = $signer->input(0, $txOut);
   $signatureType = \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Transaction\SignatureHash\SigHash::ALL | \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Transaction\SignatureHash\SigHash::BITCOINCASH;
   $input->sign($keyPairInput, $signatureType);
   $signed = $signer->get();


   echo "Witness serialized transaction: " . $signed->getHex() . '<BR><BR>';
   echo "Base serialized transaction: " . $signed->getBaseSerialization()->getHex() . '<BR><BR>';
   echo "Script validation result: " . ($input->verify() ? "yes\n" : "no\n"). '<BR><BR>';

   die();
```

In this case I get the result:

```
Script validation result: no
```

Trying to [broadcast the BCH transaction](https://blockdozer.com/tx/send) gives an error:

```
An error occured:
16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation). Code:-26
```

I think, it means, that signature is wrong. If we remove the flag `$signatureType` (keep this default), then `Script validation result` will be `yes`,  but broadcasting will give an error:

```
16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must use SIGHASH_FORKID). Code:-26
```

I think, it means - transaction signed as in bitcoin network, must to be signed by bitcoin-cash rules. Maybe I'm wrong. But bitcoin transaction signing is fine. Bitwasp has no manuals, how to sign a bitcoin-cash transactions, I have the same code for bitwasp v.0.0.34.2 (without addon "btccom/bitwasp-bitcoin-bch-addon", using `$signer->redeemBitcoinCash(true);` function) but it gives the same result.

It is interesting that in code of bitcoin-cash signer it takes the inner variable `amount` and include it in hash:

```
$hasher = new V1Hasher($this->transaction, $this->amount);
```

But for bitcoin bitwasp doesn't take the amount, presumably it takes an amount from the transaction.

Help me please to sign the transaction, bitwasp has only bitcoin examples, not bitcoin-cash. It is very difficult to find any informaion about php altcoins signing without third-party software. Regards.

Comment: You didn't posted a real private key, did you ?

Comment: @AymDev yes, it is not real private key, but i can post the real if needed, it contains just half a dollar :) The main thing is find out how to send transactions..

Answer (score 2):

This code to sign a bitcoin-cash transaction with PHP bitwasp v.0.0.35 library is works!

```
    $unspendedTx = '49343e0a4ef29b819f87df1371c6f8eafa1f235074a27fb6aa5f4ab4c48e5c16';
    $utxOutputIndex = 0;
    $utxoPrivateKey = 'MyPrIvAtEKey';
    $utxoAmount = 300000;
    $reciverPublicKey = '1E8XaWNsCWyVaZaWTLh8uBdAZjLQqwWmzM';
    $fee = 1000;

    $networkObject = \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Network\NetworkFactory::bitcoinCash();

    $outpoint = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\OutPoint(\BitWasp\Buffertools\Buffer::hex($unspendedTx, 32), $utxOutputIndex /* index of utxo in transaction, generated it */);
    $destination = \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Script\ScriptFactory::scriptPubKey()->payToPubKeyHash( (new \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Address\AddressCreator())->fromString($reciverPublicKey)->getHash() );

    $transaction = \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\TransactionFactory::build()
        ->spendOutPoint($outpoint)
        ->output($utxoAmount - $fee, $destination)
        ->get();
    echo "Unsigned transaction: " . $transaction->getHex() . '<BR><BR>';


    $keyPairInput = \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory::fromWif($utxoPrivateKey, null, $networkObject);
    $txOut = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\TransactionOutput($utxoAmount, \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Script\ScriptFactory::scriptPubKey()->payToPubKeyHash(  $keyPairInput->getPubKeyHash() ) );
    $signer = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\Factory\Signer($transaction);

    $signatureChecker = \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Transaction\Factory\Checker\CheckerCreator::fromEcAdapter( \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin::getEcAdapter() ); // for version 0.0.35
    $signer->setCheckerCreator( $signatureChecker ); // for version 0.0.35

    $input = $signer->input(0, $txOut);
    $signatureType = \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Transaction\SignatureHash\SigHash::ALL | \Btccom\BitcoinCash\Transaction\SignatureHash\SigHash::BITCOINCASH;
    $input->sign($keyPairInput, $signatureType);
    $signed = $signer->get();


    echo "Transaction: " . $signed->getHex() . '<BR><BR>';
    die();
```

I had broadcasted this PHP-generated test transaction, see [link to tx](https://www.blocktrail.com/BCC/tx/476819b29d4101f7ef35b108e78bb659acb07113602a7e53fdc9c38e10fb1509). Problaly the problem was in

```
->payToAddress($utxoAmount - $fee, $addressCreator->fromString($reciverPublicKey, $networkObject) )
```

Maybe `payToAddress` has a bug, because "hand" script creation gives another transaction. Second:

```
$txOut = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\TransactionOutput($utxoAmount  - $fee, $signScript);
```

We must to create tx input(previous output) without the fee.

Used libraries ( *composer.json* ):

```
{
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=7.0",
        "bitwasp/bitcoin": "0.0.35.0",
        "btccom/bitwasp-bitcoin-bch-addon" : "0.0.2"
    }
}
```

Hope, this will help for all altcoin api creators on PHP.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I got stuck for many hours and this line is the main culprit:
`$txOut = new \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Transaction\TransactionOutput($utxoAmount, \BitWasp\Bitcoin\Script\ScriptFactory::scriptPubKey()->payToPubKeyHash(  $keyPairInput->getPubKeyHash() ) );`
I forgot to inclute the fee on the output amount and the transaction always fail to broadcast.